# How to make a this css animation responsive?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, animation, responsive

I created a simple site using CSS3 animation. Is there any way to make it responsive?

Link: http://dollarz.comli.com/

Edit: 
I've tried bootstrap to make the image responsive but couldn't make the animation responsive.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: radial-gradient(#009acc, #363795);
  background-color: #221e05;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Georgia', 'trajan pro', 'serif';
}
header {
  width: 570px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  perspective: 500px;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 52px;
  line-height: 24px;
}
h3 {
  text-align: right;
  font-family: 'Dancing Script', 'brush script std', 'sans-serif';
  font-size: 26px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  line-height: 10px;
  color: #f2af1a;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.puzzle {
  width: 800px;
  height: 457px;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  background-image: url('http://dollarz.comli.com/Maze%20Puzzle.gif');
  position: relative;
}
.ball {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #f2af1a;
  border-radius: 100%;
  top: 150px;
  left: 45px;
  animation: movement 20s ease 3s infinite;
}
@keyframes movement {
    0% { top: 200px; left:  45px; }
    5% { top: 273px; left:  45px; }
   10% { top: 273px; left: 136px; }
   20% { top: 162px; left: 136px; }
   30% { top: 162px; left: 360px; }
   40% { top: 105px; left: 360px; }
   50% { top: 105px; left: 417px; }
   60% { top: 332px; left: 417px; }
   70% { top: 332px; left: 473px; }
   75% { top: 220px; left: 473px; }
   80% { top: 220px; left: 587px; }
   85% { top: 110px; left: 587px; }
   90% { top: 110px; left: 645px; }
   95% { top: 257px; left: 645px; }
  100% { top: 257px; left: 732px; }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Solving Maze Puzzle</h1>
  <h3>..Using CSS Animation</h3>
</header>

<div class="puzzle">
  <div class="ball"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: in general you should post your actual html and css, not a link that could change at any moment and become irrelevant.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems have you encountered? Please share a [MCVE].

Comment: @Shaggy I've tried applying bootstrap "img-responsive" class to make image responsive, but couldn't find a way to make animation responsive.

Comment: @RachelS added html and css code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give it a max width to make sure it doesn't get cut off.

```
.puzzle {
        width: 800px;
        height: 457px;
        margin: 50px auto 0;
        background-image: url('Maze Puzzle.gif');
        position: relative;
        max-width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
```